# Is there a java hash structure with keys only and no values?

Tags: java, list, hash, collections

I'm looking for a structure which hashes keys without requiring a value.  When queried, it should return true if the key is found and false otherwise.  I'm looking for something similar to 
`Hashtable<MyClass, Boolean>` 
except insertion requires only a key and queries only ever return true or false, never null.

Answer (score 78):

You need Java's [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) ([Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)).

The description from [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null
>   element.
>
> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations
>   (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses
>   the elements properly among the buckets. Iterating over this set
>   requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size
>   (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap
>   instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set
>   the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if
>   iteration performance is important.
>
> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally. This is
>   typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally
>   encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set should be
>   "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedSet method. This is best
>   done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to
>   the set:
>
> Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator
>   throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of
>   concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly,
>   rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an
>   undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.
>
> This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 14):

java.util.HashSet?  Using contains() for your lookup.

Comment: May be obvious because it's an "hash", but, the contains() method's expected time complexity is O(1).

Answer (score 2):

See also the static methods `Collections#newSetFromMap` that creates a set based on the given map implementation. This is eg handy to create a weak hash set.

Answer (score 0):

Java Set is designed to remove duplicates and hopefully the HashMap must be using Java **Set** internally for managing key as keys can never have duplicates, So you should be considering set for your requirement.

Comment: On contrary, HashSet uses HashMap internally, and HashMap uses array of some kind of linked list (created from Entry.HashMap)