# Does the Java API or an open source library provide for a TreeMap-like data structure with constant-time lookup?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, treemap

I get that a TreeMap has log(n) insertion and lookup runtime complexity.  However, a HashMap pointing to nodes in a linked list will provide for the same runtime complexity, but also constant-time lookup, which is a pretty big advantage.  However, you would have to implement the search/insert/delete functionality yourself.  I'm wondering if something in Java or another open-source library provides this for you?

I do realize that TreeMap's red-black tree might be better suited than a HashMap in certain situations, but certainly constant time lookup with natural-ordering is preferable in others.

NOTE: I know LinkedHashMap provides a built-in linked list for insertion order, but I'm talking about maintaining natural ordering like a TreeMap would do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460088/is-there-a-java-hash-structure-with-keys-only-and-no-values

Comment: Does a linking hash map provide constant time look-up? That doesn't sound correct to me. Doesn't it has a O(N) worst case on all operations?

Comment: i think it has O(N) worst case but correct me if im wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162501/worse-case-time-complexity-put-get-hashmap

Comment: Also, does a linking hash map doesn't provide a natural ordering iteration between buckets. I wouldn't think so.

Comment: @Dlotan Yea, you are correct. It was a mis-type :-)

Comment: I'm not referring to a LinkedHashMap, which I think you were referring to... that only provides insertion order.  I'll add clarification.

Comment: @sdanzig No, I wasn't referring to a linked hash map. I was referring to a hash map where each bucket is a linked list. Isn't that what you are referring to also, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Justin Nope, meant each bucket, optimally, has a single node in a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if your keys adhere to a pattern that you can take advantage of in the data structure.

A good example would be a `TrieMap`. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for a description and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/623892/823393) for a discussion containing references to implementations.

I posted a Trie implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320920/823393) some time ago. Not sure how efficient it is but it works. I have certainly improved it since that post.

Comment: Not quite constant time operations.

Comment: @Justin - `O(M)` lookup which is arguably constant if your keys *adhere to a pattern* of being constant length.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to make sure that information was included.

Comment: A space efficient radix trie implementation I've written:  http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/PatriciaTrie.java